# SQL: How to group data into bands

Tags: sql, grouping

I've created a query that shows the number of times an individual client appears in a list of transactions....

```
select Client_Ref, count(*)
from Transactions
where Start_Date >= '2015-01-01'
group by Client_Ref
order by Client_Ref
```

...this returns data like this...

```
Client1   1
Client2   4
Client3   1
Client4   3
```

..What I need to do is summarize this into bands of frequency so that I get something like this...

```
No. of Clients with 1 transaction   53
No. of Clients with 2 transaction   157
No. of Clients with 3 transaction   25
No. of Clients with >3 transactions 259
```

I can't think how to so this in SQL, I could probably figure it out in Excel but I'd rather it was done at server level.

Comment: best would be to show us table structure, that way youll get answer faster

Comment: This is just one table that contains a list of transactions/interactions and I'm simply counting the number of instances that a Client_Ref appears.

Comment: In that case,you can try to use your query as inner select, something like this 


select Counted, count(Client_ref) from (
 select Client_Ref, count(*) Counted
 from Transactions
 where Start_Date >= '2015-01-01'
 group by Client_Ref) as src
group by Counted 
order by 2 desc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I call this a "histogram of histogram" query.  Just use `group by` twice:

```
select cnt, count(*), min(CLlient_Ref), max(Client_Ref)
from (select Client_Ref, count(*) as cnt
      from Transactions
      where Start_Date >= '2015-01-01'
      group by Client_Ref
     ) t
group by cnt
order by cnt;
```

I include the min and max client ref, because I often want to investigate certain values further.

If you want a limit at 3, you can use `case`:

```
select (case when cnt <= 3 then cast(cnt as varchar(255)) else '4+' end) as grp,
       count(*), min(CLlient_Ref), max(Client_Ref)
from (select Client_Ref, count(*) as cnt
      from Transactions
      where Start_Date >= '2015-01-01'
      group by Client_Ref
     ) t
group by (case when cnt <= 3 then cast(cnt as varchar(255)) else '4+' end) 
order by min(cnt);
```

Comment: Perfect! ....the second query using case statements gives me exactly what I need - Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
select cnt, count(*) from
(
select case count(*) when 1 then 'No. of Clients with 1 transaction'
                     when 2 then 'No. of Clients with 2 transactions'
                     when 3 then 'No. of Clients with 3 transactions'
                            else 'No. of Clients with >3 transactions'
       end as cnt
from Transactions
where Start_Date >= '2015-01-01'
group by Client_Ref
)
group by cnt
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a conditional `SUM()` to pull the total for each grouping:

```
Select  'No. of Clients with 1 transaction' = Sum(Case When A.Total = 1 Then 1 Else 0 End),
        'No. of Clients with 2 transactions' = Sum(Case When A.Total = 2 Then 1 Else 0 End),
        'No. of Clients with 3 transactions' = Sum(Case When A.Total = 3 Then 1 Else 0 End),
        'No. of Clients with >3 transactions' = Sum(Case When A.Total > 3 Then 1 Else 0 End)
From    
(
    Select  Client_Ref, count(*) As Total
    From    Transactions
    Where   Start_Date >= '2015-01-01'
    Group by Client_Ref
) A
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create the buckets separately and then use a `union all`:

```
with COUNT1 as (
select Client_Ref, count(*) as count1
from Transactions
where Start_Date >= '2015-01-01'
group by Client_Ref
order by Client_Ref
    )
,COUNT2 as (
select cast(C.count1 as varchar(5)) as count1,count(Client_Ref) as count2
from COUNT1 C
where count1 <= 3
group by C.count1
    )
,COUNT3 as (
select '> 3' as count1,count(*) as count2
from COUNT1 C
where C.count1 > 3
    )

select * from COUNT2
union all
select * from COUNT3
```

You can manually enter that text ('No. of Clients with N transactions') if you want to.

Answer (score 0):

```
select Client_Ref
    ,count(*) as Count
    ,case when count(*) < 4 then count(*) else 4 end as Band
from Transactions
where Start_Date >= '2015-01-01'
group by Client_Ref
order by Client_Ref
```